# NHibernate Custom HQL for loading

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

The following is from the NHibernate documentation:

15.4. Custom SQL for loading You may also declare your own SQL **(or HQL)** queries for entity loading:

```
<sql-query name="person">
    <return alias="pers" class="Person" lock-mode="upgrade"/>
    SELECT NAME AS {pers.Name}, ID AS {pers.Id}
    FROM PERSON
    WHERE ID=?
    FOR UPDATE
</sql-query>
```

This is just a named query declaration, as discussed earlier. You may reference this named query in a class mapping:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="Id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="Name" not-null="true"/>
    <loader query-ref="person"/>
</class>
```

There isn't an example given for using HQL.  I tried to simply replace `<sql-query>` with `<query>` and then replace the SQL query with an HQL query.  This results in the exception "Named SQL query not known".  Is there a way to tell it to look for an HQL query instead of an SQL query?

Comment: what does your actual HQL <query> element look like? can you get the named query using `session.GetNamedQuery("person")` ?

Comment: I can get and execute the named query using session.GetNamedQuery("queryName").  

The error message explicitly says it is looking for a "SQL query".  Is there any way in the <loader> statement to tell it to look for an HQL query instead of an SQL query?

Comment: I don't see anything in particular that would limit the loader to be SQL only. Can you create a stand-alone test?

Comment: Did you every find out the reason for this error? I'm getting the same when loading a Set with a named Hql query. Probably a misleading error message. I'll keep at it...